# form action onsubmit redirect with input value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I tried to like this... but its not work how to correct it.

i want to redirect like this `example.com/search/[search+text]`

source code

```
<form name="menu_search" action="load.php" method="get" onsubmit="window.location.href = document.getElementById('videoSearch'); return false;" >

        <input name="q" id="videoSearch" />

      </form>
```

onsubmit not work :( also i try to like this. but it also not work. plz help fot this one. `onsubmit="window.location.href = ' + value.videoSearch + '; return false;"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
    <form name="menu_search" action="load.php" method="get" onsubmit="document.location.href = 'http://example.com/search/'+this.q.value+''; return false;" >

    <input name="q" id="videoSearch" />

  </form>
```

Comment: woow.. amazing.. can fix to like this.. now we input english videos its redirect to like this.. example.com/search/english%20videos  > i want to like this example.com/search/english+videos

Comment: Did this work for you? Worked for me, from here it should be self-explanatory on how to make those changes you are asking for in the comments. Nonetheless, an up-vote would be nice, thanks :)

Comment: for search spaces can u add +

Comment: You don't need to add + to the query string, the browser will do it for your automatically.